# How do I make my local webserver accessible to others on my network?

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver

I've got a MacBook running MAMP.

I want others on my team (who are on the same network) to be able to access my local webserver so they can test their client code against my RESTful API's on my server.

We have an Apple Time Capsule/Airport router.

Firewall is turned off on my Mac.

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `http://your.macs.ip.address`?  Presuming Apache's set up properly it should be listening on all network interfaces on the machine.

Comment: Accessing "http://localhost" from my browser works fine. But when I tried go to my Mac's IP address with my iPhone, I got an error msg that Safari couldn't connect to the server. And when I tried to telnet to my IP address from my Mac, the error msg say "connection refused.. unable to connect to remote host." I don't have a firewall running on my Mac. Why can't my iPhone connect to my MAMP server?

Comment: can the other users ping your ip at least? If they can't even do that, then you've got other issues beyond trying to get Apache going right.

Comment: My httpd.conf file already has "Listen 80" directive, so apache is listening on port 80 on all IP addresses. The Firewall is turned off. When I try to ping 192.168.15.12:80 (my laptop's IP address and port 80), I get "cannot resolve 192.168.15.12:80: unknown host".

Comment: you can't ping a port, just an IP. pings work at the ICMP level, which has no ports.

Comment: Ok - I can ping my IP address 192.168.15.12. But when I try to access this IP address from my iPhone's browser, it resolves to "localhost/" in the URL bar, and thus cannot connect.

Comment: Probably apache is serving itself up as "localhost", which on every machines means ITSELF - you need to get it to NOT redirect to the non-IP address, and/or assign it a proper dns name (even if it's just a static mapping in everyone's hosts file).

Comment: In httpd.conf, I changed ServerName from "localhost:80" to "192.168.15.12:80", but the redirect to localhost still happens. Which file do I change to remove this redirect? Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart apache? .conf changes require a restart/reload.

Comment: yes, I restarted apache.

Comment: I figured it out. My .htaccess file was doing a rewrite to "localhost". Thanks, Marc B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all Apache configuration files (httpd.conf and .htaccess) to check for URL rewrites.

Turns out that my .htaccess file in my root was doing a rewrite to "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

Well first see if you can connect to it yourself.
From a shell try telnet localhost 80
and see if it answers.
If not, it's not even listening, need to set that up first.

If that works, try telnetting from other machines on your network to yours (telnet yourmachinesiporname 80)  and see if they have connectivity.

You might find your company's firewall blocks things like port 80 so you can't do things like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a firewall, make sure it's configured to allow connections on the appropriate port (usually 80, but with a local server it can be different).
2. Make sure the server is properly configured to accept connections from remote hosts.
3. Make sure your company's routers allow internal connections on the appropriate ports.

Comment: No firewall running on my Mac. My MAMP server is listening on port 80, but there are no configuration options to accept/deny connections from remote hosts. My Apple Airport doesn't have any IP port access control config options. See above for edits.

Answer (score 0):

For those who will land on this page in future and want to access their MAMP server by accessible to others on their network (by IP), add this as the very first `<VirtualHost *:80>` either with the default MacOS Apache server or with MAMP (for MAMP, put it after `NameVirtualHost *:80`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/web/root
</VirtualHost>
```

(where `/path/to/web/root` = `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` for MAMP, & = `/Library/WebServer/Documents` for the default MacOS Apache server)